# MongoDB: Are bulk operations written to the oplog as a whole?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

When I issue an ordered bulk operation in MongoDB 3, is the bulk operation as a whole written to the oplog so that it can be replayed as a whole after a server crash?

The rationale for this question is the following:

I know that there are no real transactions but that I can use the `$isolated` keyword to have some read consistency (in some cases). 
Apart from being good schema design or not, let's assume that I would have to update multiple documents in possibly different collections in one go, in what would be a transaction in SQL. I do not care about the data being in an inconsistent state at any near moment, however I do require the data to be consistent *eventually*. So, while I may not care about errors and missing rollbacks during the operation, I require the sequence of updates to be *performed entirely* or *not performed at all* at some point, in order to have them survive unexpected server failures or shutdowns in the middle of the bulk operation (because of, say, random CoreOS updates).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will enter into this with the general caveat that I admit I have not even looked at the results, but the basic principles seem valid to me from the start.

What you need to consider here is "what is actually happening under the hood" of the "nice syntax sugar" you are presented with in general calls. What this means is basically looking at what the "command form" of the operations you are calling actually do. In this case ["update"](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/).

So, if you had a look at that link already, then consider the following ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) update form:

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrdedBulkOp();

bulk.find({ "_id": 1 }).updateOne({ "$set": { "a": 1 } });
bulk.find({ "_id": 2 }).updateOne({ "$set": { "b": 2 } });

bulk.execute();
```

Now you already know this is being sent to the server as **one** request, but what you are likely not considering is that actual "request" made "under the hood" is actually this:

```js
db.runCommand({
    "update": "collection",
    "updates": [
        { "q": { "_id": 1 }, "u": { "$set": { "a": 1 } } },
        { "q": { "_id": 2 }, "u": { "$set": { "b": 2 } } }
    ],
    "ordered": true
})
```

Therefore it stands to reason that what you actually see in the logs under the "update" operation is actually something like (abbreviated from full output to just the query):

```js
{ "q": { "_id": 1 }, "u": { "$set": { "a": 1 } } }
{ "q": { "_id": 2 }, "u": { "$set": { "b": 2 } } }
```

Which therefore means that each of those actions with the associated command is in the oplog for "replay" on replication and/or on other actions you might perform such as specifically "replaying" the oplog entries.

I'd be sure that is what actually happens without even looking, because I know that it how the drivers implement the actual calls, and it makes sense that each call is kept within the oplog in this way.

Therefore "as a whole", then no. These are not "transactions" and are always distinct operations even if their submission and return are within a singular request. But they are **not** a singular operation, and therefore will not and should not be recorded as such.

Comment: Not sure I got that right, but your conclusion seems to be contradicting what you said above; then again, maybe I'm just asking stupidly. So, different approach: Are the individual updates written to the oplog before the work on the first one begins or can the system be in a state where not all individual updates are "registered", so that technically any amount of them could be lost?

Comment: @sunside I thought it was quite clear. Send as "one request" with one response, but "commit" as "separate operations". So each update should in fact be a separate oplog entry, and not a "batch" of operations. "Technically" I also stated "not a transaction", so there is no "guarantee" ( if you did not get the confirm response and the server crashed during ) that all requests submitted in the batch were "all" committed anyway. That is just how MongoDB basically works.

Comment: This one I got (I think), I'm just wondering if the internal behaviour is, basically, `take first, register first, perform first, take next, register, perform, ...` or more along the lines of `register all, perform first, perform next, ...`.

Seems you updated your comment in the meantime. Do you know of any trivial solution around that, apart from two-phase commits?

Comment: @sunside What I am basically saying is that is it nothing like that. Consider "unordered" operations as a batch request. This basically means that all operations in the batch are applied in "any order", therefore meaning as "separate" operations and on different "threads" ( internally speaking ). In both cases there is also the "Error" response to consider, where it only makes sense to "apply" those operations that suceeded and not those that errored. No point in "replaying" things that cannot result in a modification or insert is there?

Comment: @sunside You actual question does not ask for a "specific solution to a specific problem", but just rather generally asks "how does this work?". Therefore that is the answer I gave. If you have a "specific" problem to solve, then I suggest you ask that in [Another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). Where the already hinted answer would be "perform two phase commits" along the easily searchable exact term in the core MongoDB documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with that procedure. ;)

Comment: @sunside Well it is th basic procedure to "that" problem. ie. Mark "in process", do stuff, come back and mark "complete". No "transactions" here. Just us bears.