# How does mongodb update work internally?

Tags: mongodb

Lets say I have a document like this

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("544946347db27ca99e20a95f"), "name" : "Foo Bar",'firstName':"foo", "lastName":"bar" }
```

If I perform two separate updates like this

```
update({'_id':'544946347db27ca99e20a95f'},{$set:{'lastName':'BARBAR'}})
update({'_id':'544946347db27ca99e20a95f'},{$set:{'name':'Foo BARBAR'}})
```

Is it like two separate transactions or does it aggregate both of them and do a single write?

If I have to learn more about the internal workings, what should I be searching for?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Do they aggreggate? Never. Related: [MongoDB: Are bulk operations written to the oplog as a whole?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32156700/5031275)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is two different *update* operations.

In  almost all MongoDB Operators you can use many fields. So the best way is:

```js
db.collection.update({ '_id':'544946347db27ca99e20a95f'}, { 
    '$set': { 'lastName': 'BARBAR', 'name': 'Foo BARBAR' }
})
```

You can learn more about Operators in the official [documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/). For example the [`$set`](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator has the following syntax:

> `{ $set: { <field1>: <value1>, ... } }`

You may want to use the ["Bulk"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) API and in this case rewrite your function so that the can take a *bulk* object argument.

```js
var bulk = db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();

function foo(bulk){
    // do something
    bulk.find({ "_id": "544946347db27ca99e20a95f" }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "lastName": "BARBAR" }
   // do another thing
    });
}

function bar(bulk){
    // do something
    bulk.find({ "_id": "544946347db27ca99e20a95f" }).updateOne({ 
        "$set": { "name": "Foo BARBAR" }
   // do another thing
    });
}


foo(bulk);
bar(bulk);
bulk.execute();
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I know that I can update multiple fields in a single update statement.
If I'm updating the two fields of a document in two separate functions, that are called few milliseconds apart, do they run as separate updates?

I was expecting it to Q the write operations and then push one by one, and during this it may aggregate two updates if they are on the same document?

Comment: @SatishGandham as I said it No it is two different operations. if you really want to do something before "committing" bulk operations is the way to go. Edited my answer.