# Are bulk inserts atomic in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, atomic, bulkinsert

I am learning about mongodb. If I create a bulk write is this transaction all or nothing? I have a scenario where my users can delete who they are friends with.

```
FRIEND 1  |  FRIEND 2
  User B     USER A
  User A     USER B
```

For this to happen I need to delete from both bidirectional relationships. For consistency I need these to occur as a all or nothing because I wouldn't want only 1 of the 2 operations to succeed as this would cause bad data. Reading the docs I could not find the answer:

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/

Comment: Related: [Are Bulk Operations Written to the Op-Log as a whole?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156700/mongodb-are-bulk-operations-written-to-the-oplog-as-a-whole/32156839#32156839). But anything that succeeds will be written as there is no built in concept of "rollback". Also noting that "un-ordered" operations batches will write every operation that does not error, as opposed to "ordered" where the writes will cease on the first error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

db.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp()
"If an error occurs during the processing of one of the write operations, MongoDB will return without processing **any remaining write** operations in the list."

No mention of rollback ops, simply stops inserting the remaining.

db.collection.insert() method
["The insert() method, when passed an array of documents, performs a bulk insert, and inserts **each document atomically**."](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.4/core/bulk-inserts/)

you can roll your own . but use [acknowledged write concern](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/) which would have to be via your chosen driver. shell is acknowledged but perhaps driver is not.

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-concern/

```
try
   insert 1
catch 
  delete

try
   insert 2
catch 
  delete 1
  delete 2
```

Comment: Ahhh Thank you! So it looks like it is not atomic, only the individual requests are atomic.

Comment: there are a few nosql that are transactional aka have acid-ness. orientdb and neo4j but personally i would use some simple try catch if null appl logic

Comment: mongo 4.0 supports ACID!