# Are MongoDB bulk updates atomic if they apply to the same document?

Tags: mongodb, atomic, bulkupdate, interleave

For the following command where `query` can only ever match one document (note that `bulkWrite()` is ordered by default):

```
final BulkWriteResult res = db.getCollection("mycol").bulkWrite(Arrays.asList(
    new UpdateOneModel<>(query,
        new Document("$addToSet", new Document("some_things", things))),
    new UpdateOneModel<>(query,
        new Document("$pull", new Document("some_things", otherthings)))));
```

... I understand that if the first update succeeds and the second fails (which under normal circumstances should be impossible) the [first update will still be applied to the document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111000/are-bulk-inserts-atomic-in-mongodb), which means the bulk write isn't strictly atomic. However, assuming both queries succeed, is the operation atomic? E.g. can other writes interleave between the two operations or not?