# Bulk insert/update with umongo

Tags: python, mongodb, bulkinsert, bulkupdate, umongo

I would like to perform bulk insert/update with the umongo library in Python. Is there a way to do the bulk update all at once or am I going to run one insert/update job per item to update ?

Answer (score 0):

umongo doesn't do bulk update.

What you could do is call `to_mongo` on each document to build the bulk insert/update payload, then call YourDocument.collection.insert/update with that payload.

Beware, the bulk insert/update operation is [not atomic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34111000/are-bulk-inserts-atomic-in-mongodb) (independently from umongo).